# mgo - bson.ObjectId vs string id

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

Using `mgo`, it seems that best practice is to set object ids to be `bson.ObjectId`.

This is not very convenient, as the result is that instead of a plain `string` id the id is stored as binary in the DB. Googling this seems to yield tons of questions like "how do I get a string out of the bson id?", and indeed in `golang` there is the `Hex()` method of the `ObjectId` to allow you to get the string.

The bson becomes even more annoying to work with when exporting data from mongo to another DB platform (this is the case when dealing with big data that is collected and you want to merge it with some properties from the back office mongo DB), this means a lot of pain (you need to transform the binary ObjectId to a string in order to join with the id in different platforms that do not use bson representation).

My question is: what are the benefits of using `bson.ObjectId` vs `string` id? Will I lose anything significant if I store my `mongo` entities with a plain string id?

Comment: How would you generate a string that meets the uniqueness requirements? Calling `ID.Hex()` when dealing with the ObjectID externally doesn't have any downsides - using your own string ID would as it would be larger (24 bytes vs. 12 bytes for ObjectID) and make your implementation more brittle.

Comment: It's fairly simple to generate a UUID string. Using ObjectId mechanism for this purpose seems redundant. Furthermore it has the downside of being incompatible with any system that doesn't use bson data types

Comment: The hex representation is portable/compatible. A UUIDv4 is no different - in fact databases like Postgres store UUIDs as byte arrays, not strings.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess the downsides of bson are use-case specific. However my questions still stands (what are the benefits of using bson.ObjectId vs string id? Will I lose anything significant if I store my mongo entities with a plain string id?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, storing the ObjectId as a hex string would double the space needed for it and in case you want to extract one of its values, you'd first need to construct an ObjectId from that string.

But you have a misconception. There is *absolutely* no need to use an ObjectId for the mandatory `_id` field. Quite often, I advice against that. Here is why.

Take the simple example of a book, relations and some other considerations set aside for simplicty:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("56b0d36c23da2af0363abe37"),
  isbn: "978-3453056657",
  title: "Neuromancer",
  author: "William Gibson",
  language: "German"
}
```

Now, what use would have the ObjectId here? Actually none. It would be an index with hardly any use, since you would never search your book databases by an artificial key like that. It holds no semantic value. It would be a unique ID for an object which already *has* a globally unique ID – the ISBN.

So we simplify our book document like this:

```
{
  _id: "978-3453056657",
  title: "Neuromancer",
  author: "William Gibson",
  language: "German"
}
```

We have reduced the size of the document, make use of a preexisting globally unique ID and do not have a basically unused index.

Back to your basic question wether you loose something by not using ObjectIds: Quite often, not using the ObjectId is the better choice. But if you use it, use the binary form.